# How can I show median gray level image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image and I find median and deviation in blocks of 5*5 in my image and save it to the    and     images. now when I show the results they are mask of the original image while it should not be so. it should show me a blur image in gray level not black and white!!. Do you know what mistake I have made?

here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('M.png', 0)

win = 5   # block window
height, width = img.shape   

MedianOfBlock = []   
DeviationOfBlock = []

for i in range(0, (height-2*win)):
    MedianOfBlock.append([])
    DeviationOfBlock.append([])
    for j in range(0, (width- 2*win)):
       block = np.array(img[i:i+win, j:j+win])

      # Compute the median in each window
      MedianOfBlock[i].append(np.median(block))

      # Compute the standard deviation in each window
DeviationOfBlock[i].append(FindDeviation(block,MedianOfBlock[i][j],  win))

DeviationOfBlock2 = np.array(DeviationOfBlock)
MedianOfBlock2 = np.array(MedianOfBlock)
cv2.imshow('OriginalImage',img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imshow('MedianImage',MedianOfBlock2 )
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imshow('DeviationOfBlock',DeviationOfBlock2 )
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a test image (e.g. `img = np.ones(5,5)`)?  Or have you stepped through it with `python -m pdb your_script.py`?  Those are first steps for any programmer.

Comment: oh I just wasted one day working on this pdb!!! I do not need it since I am using Pycharm.

Comment: moreover what I have written in Python, the same I have written in MATLAB and there I get proper results. but here I do not find why??!!!

Comment: If you step through the process (pdb or PyCharm), you can identify the faulty step(s) if you are using a ***simple*** test image.  

Start with test images that you can compute by hand and increase in complexity until you observe the behavior.   From experience, just because it 'works' in MATLAB doesn't mean the result is correct, so you can't assume it's correct unless you have TESTED the code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).  

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying do image filtering, this process is done by kernel convolution, the Opencv module have a function called `cv2.filter2D`. You can do a image filtering with the median kernel that use a averaging kernel.

```
   import cv2
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

   img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')

   kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
   dst = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)

   plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Original')
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Averaging')
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.show()
```

Obs: if you don't have the `matplotlib` module, just install it or use the default plot function from Opencv

Plase check the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: No I do not want to do filtering. I just need to find the medians in each block for further processing.